# I want to create an animation circle that play always and allow click even

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello guys I want my animation be infinite and when it finish - he restart without any jump space.
and moreover allow to click event to go next position on my animation circle
How can I apply it?

```js
let jump = 0;
let index = 0;

const boxContainer = document.querySelector(".boxContainer");

const animate = () => {
  boxContainer.style.transform = `translate(${jump}px)`;
  boxContainer.appendChild(boxContainer.children[index].cloneNode(true));
  index++;
};

const nextBox = () => {
  jump -= 100;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.anim {
  animation: anim 10s infinite linear;
}

.boxContainer {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.boxContainer > .box {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.container > button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 32px;
  width: 50px;
}

@keyframes anim {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-1000px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="anim">

    <div class="boxContainer">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
      <div class="box">7</div>
      <div class="box">8</div>
      <div class="box">9</div>
      <div class="box">10</div>
      <div class="box">11</div>
      <div class="box">12</div>
      <div class="box">13</div>
      <div class="box">14</div>
      <div class="box">15</div>
      <div class="box">16</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="nextBox()">next box</button>
</div>
```

As you can see I create at animation that allow that click event nad he jump to next position but in some place animation restart in wrong place.

How to fix that issue in right and performance way ?

Comment: `index` is not synchronized with jumps, you've to update `index` when showing the next box. Also, it looks like you'd add new boxes when appending the current box to the right, that's probably not intentional, just append the element, don't clone it.

Comment: Why not clone it? if I only use appending it take from start

Comment: Cloning a box will add a new box to the animation. You can't see it though, because it lies outside of the 500px range, but when never removed, the extra elements will take a lot of memory, if a visitor stays on your page and diligently clicks the next button. You could jump to the correct index (without the transition effect) when moving the box to the right end.

Comment: I think i can remove it when animation start over (restart), but I need to do it and include animation keep display without any restart issue (no jumps between restart animation)

Comment: Please help someone